How to store all pixel coordinates of a line in a 5x5 matrix using OpenCV in C++?
I have two points, (x1, y1) and (x2, y2), and I want to draw a line connecting these two points. After drawing the line, I need to determine all the coordinates that the line passes through and store this information in a 5x5 matrix. The starting point (x1, y1) should be considered the center of this 5x5 matrix.
For example, if my starting point is (6, 3) and the end point is (3, 8), I want to store all the indices of the line that fall within this 5x5 matrix centered at (6, 3).
How can I achieve this in C++ using OpenCV? Any code snippets or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
LineIterator it(grid, start, end, Scalar(255), 1, LINE_AA);
for (int m = 0; m < it.count; m++, ++it) {
    Point pos = it.pos();
    if (pos.x >= 0 && pos.x < 5 && pos.y >= 0 && pos.y < 5) {
        grid.at<uint16_t>(pos) = 1; 
    }
}


I have tried this, but it doesn't seem to help. How can I properly determine the coordinates and store them in the matrix? Is there a better way to handle this using OpenCV's functionality?

It isn't clear at all what you want. Can you show the complete 5x5 matrix for these two points?

Here’s what I mean
[0 0 0 0 0],
[0 0 1 0 0],
[0 1 0 0 0]
[1 0 0 0 0],
[0 0 0 0 0]
This 5x5 matrix represents the area centered at (6, 3) in the larger coordinate system. A 1 in the matrix indicates that the corresponding coordinate in the larger system is on the line connecting (6, 3) to (3, 8).

why should an arbitrary number of coordinates fit in a 5x5 matrix?

this literally just requires LineIterator. the rest is coding. [mre] required. definition of grid is not shown. this is not nitpicking, this matters.

You can calculate any point on a line if you have the slope and y-intercept.  You can calculate both from any pairs of (x1, y1) and (x2, y2).  Why do this you need a 5x5 matrix?

@Micka OP does use the LineIterator. the code snippet shows it. OP seems to need assistance in considering how the 5x5 ROI relates to the original image's bounds, and how to offset the generated coordinates to be in the 5x5 ROI.

Since matrix size is 5x5, if the center of 5x5 matrix is (cx,cy), top left position of this matrix is (cx-2,cx-2).
Using this, you can process all in the  5x5 matirx's coordinate system with offseting two input points as :

(x1', y1') = (x1-(cx-2), y1-(cy-2) )
(x2', y2') = (x2-(cx-2), y2-(cy-2) )

The code below is sample.
//Here,
// CenterOf5x5 is (cx,cy) mentioned above in this post.
// P1,P2 is (x1,y1) and (x2,y2).
cv::Mat Test( const cv::Point &CenterOf5x5, const cv::Point &P1, const cv::Point &P2 )
{
    cv::Mat M5x5 = cv::Mat::zeros( 5,5, CV_8U );
    cv::Point Origin = CenterOf5x5 - cv::Point(2,2);

    cv::LineIterator Iter( M5x5, P1-Origin, P2-Origin );
    int n = Iter.count;
    for( int i=0; i<n; ++i, ++Iter )
    {
        M5x5.at<unsigned char>( Iter.pos() ) = 1;
    }
    return M5x5;
}

int main()
{
    cv::Mat M = Test( {6,3}, {6,3}, {3,8} );

    std::cout << M << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

And output of this sample is:
[  0,   0,   0,   0,   0;
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0;
   0,   0,   1,   0,   0;
   0,   1,   0,   0,   0;
   1,   0,   0,   0,   0]

